# Join two tables but still get full data of first table

Tags: mysql, sql

First I have table `users`

```
+---------+----------+------------------+
| user_id | username |      email       |
+---------+----------+------------------+
|       1 | User 1   | email1@gmail.com |
|       2 | User 2   | email2@gmail.com |
|       3 | User 3   | email3@gmail.com |
|       4 | User 4   | email4@gmail.com |
+---------+----------+------------------+
```

Next I have table `user_announcement`

```
+---------+----------+---------+-----------+
| user_id | annou_id | is_read | read_time |
+---------+----------+---------+-----------+
|       1 |        1 |       0 | Time      |
|       2 |        1 |       1 | Time      |
|       1 |        2 |       0 | Time      |
|       2 |        3 |       1 | Time      |
+---------+----------+---------+-----------+
```

I am trying to figure how to get all user and their read status for announcement id 1
I want output have something like this

```
+---------+----------+------------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| user_id | username |      email       | annou_id | is_read | read_time |
+---------+----------+------------------+----------+---------+-----------+
|       1 | User 1   | email1@gmail.com | 1        | 0       | Time      |
|       2 | User 2   | email2@gmail.com | 1        | 1       | Time      |
|       3 | User 3   | email3@gmail.com | NULL     | NULL    | NULL      |
|       4 | User 4   | email4@gmail.com | NULL     | NULL    | NULL      |
+---------+----------+------------------+----------+---------+-----------+
```

I tried all kinds of join but it didn't give me the result I want.

Comment: This is what LEFT JOIN is for

Comment: @Barmar - I think this is not duplicate. OP updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing a `LEFT JOIN`, if you need to filter on a column in the second table, you should do it in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_announcement ua
ON u.user_id=ua.user_id AND ua.annou_id = 1
```

Comment: Yes, the way I did just cause a trouble. I tried your query and it seems work fine. Still testing on it.

Comment: Your way only shows the rows that have `annou_id = 1` or don't exist at all in the announcements table. You have to do it this way to get `NULL` for the rows that have announcements with annou_id != 1.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Updated answer as per user requirement

This is what you are looking for. Here I am first getting `min(annou_id)` for each user and then getting other records for that row. Now treating this derived table as second table, I am going for a left join as earlier to get the required records.

```
select u.user_id,u.username,u.email,ua_derived.annou_id,ua_derived.is_read,ua_derived.read_time
from user u
left join 
    (
            select ua1.user_id,ua1.annou_id,ua1.is_read,ua1.read_time from user_announcement ua1
        inner join 
            (select user_id,min(annou_id) as annou_id  from user_announcement
            group by user_id 
            ) ua2
        on ua1.user_id=ua2.user_id
        and ua1.annou_id=ua2.annou_id
    ) ua_derived
on u.user_id=ua_derived.user_id;
```

**SQL Fiddle demo here**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57a74/4

========================================================================

**Prev Answer:**

Answer is same as Yeldar, but you just need to use column alias to display.

```
select u.user_id,u.username,u.email,ua.annou_id,ua.is_read,ua.read_time
from user u
left join user_announcement ua
on u.user_id=ua.user_id
```

**SQL Fiddle demo here**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db28e/1

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question a bit. It won't come out well when I have more than one user_id = 1 in table `user_announcement`

Comment: So in this case, do you need minimum of `annou_id` if you have more than 1 `user_id`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp),

> The **`LEFT JOIN`** keyword returns all rows from the left table, with the matching rows in the right table. The result is `NULL` in the right side when there is no match.

That's exactly what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` AS u
LEFT JOIN `user_announcement` AS ua
ON u.user_id = ua.user_id
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question a bit. It won't come out well when I have more than one user_id = 1 in table `user_announcement`

Answer (score 0):

yes you can try this

```
select
   t1.*,
   t2.annou_id,
   t2.is_read,
   t2.read_time
from
   user t1
   left join user_announcement t2
      on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
where
   t2.annou_id = 1
order by
   t1.user_id desc
```